# Netbeans plugin (add action)

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I want create plugin for Netbeans to add some action in Netbeans to certain file types. Conditionally enabled action depends on content type. I don't know mime type for some file types and I don't know how to know it. Can I register my own content type and somehow assign it to all file types I want to process?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `FileObject`, you can use the [`FileUtil.getMIMEType`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-filesystems/org/openide/filesystems/FileUtil.html#getMIMEType(org.openide.filesystems.FileObject)) method to get the mime type.